# What is the meaning of countable sequence of sets?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading the below definitions:

[image]

The item S3. says, $\{A_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is any countable sequence of sets. I don't know what the author is trying to say. Does he mean that each $A_i$ is countable set or is he saying that the set $\{A_1, A_2, A_3,...,A_{\infty}\}$ is countable?

Comment: It is just a sequence. Indexed by positive integers. The sentence would be just as good without the word "countable" unless the book considers "sequences" indexed by more complicated creatures. The point was maybe to emphasize that there can be infinitely many.

Comment: So, basically you are saying that the set $\{A_1, A_2, A_3,....,A_{\infty}\}$ is a countable set?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, because the thing you wrote does not exist. There is no such thing as $A_\infty$. If anything, I might be saying that $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots\}$ is a countable set, but that is kind of a void statement since it is by definition. It is equivalent to the fact that the index set is countable, and that is the point.

Comment: "The union of countably many sets from F is again in F" is the best way to phrase it.

Comment: Notation $\{A_i\}_{i \in X}$ makes sense no matter what the set $X$ is. Usually we call $\{A_i\}_{i \in X}$ a "sequence" if the set $X$ is countable and has one well-defined bijection to  $\mathbb{N}$. Rather than just calling $\{A_i\}_{i \in X}$ a sequence, the book chose to be more explicit. Note that we use both "countable" and "with one obvious bijection to $\mathbb{N}$". For instance $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, but defining the "limit" of a sequence indexed by $\mathbb{Q}$ could raise weird questions unless you've specified which bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to N.

Comment: @Stef : So, do you mean that the sequence $\{A_1, A_2, A_3,.....\}$ is a countable set?

Comment: Yes, the family $\{ A_i \}_{ i \ge 1}$ has countable many elements; no assumption about the number of elements of each set $A_i$. We call it *sequence* because the family is indexed by the set of natural numbers, that as an order; in case of a generic index set $I$, the family $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ is not a "sequence".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ; What do you mean by the family $\{A_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ has countable many elements? Do you mean that the family $\{A_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ has the cardinality equal to the cardinality of the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Yes; you have written it above as $\{ A_1, A_2, \ldots \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ; Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @DrimitiveWatson No. That is not what I mean. The words "sequence" and "set" do NOT have the same definition. Those are two very different mathematical definitions. A sequence is a function whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ (or alternatively, a function whose domain is a countable set with an explicit bijection to $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @DrimitiveWatson For instance, consider family ${\left( a_i \right)}_{i \in \mathbb{R}}$ defined by $ a_i = \lfloor i \rfloor$, where $\lfloor \rfloor$ means "floor" or "integer part". Then, the set $ \{ a_i ,\, i \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is countable, but the family ${\left( a_i \right)}_{i \in \mathbb{R}}$ is uncountable, and because it is uncountable, we do not call it a sequence.

Comment: @DrimitiveWatson A sequence or a family ${\left( a_i \right)}_{i \in X}$ is a function. The corresponding set $ \{ a_i ,\, i \in X \}$ is the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of that function.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the set is countable if it's cardinality is the same as the cardinality of set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...,n,...\}$.
The cardinalities of two sets are equal if we have bijection between these two sets, so if you have bijection between set $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ you can "count" elements of $A$ using natural numbers.
And in this case notation $\{A_i\}_{i \geq 1}$ is just a shortcut for set $A = \{A_1, A_2,..., A_n ... \}$ which is countable by it's definition : we have a bijection $f : A \mapsto
 \mathbb{N} : \forall i : A_i \in A \ f(A_i)=i \in \mathbb{N}$.